# Zend Framework : Problem with a Big database

Tags: php, zend-framework, memory-management

I am working on a project concerning a personalised search engine.
I came upon Zend Framework when i was searching for a way to optimize the time of search results.

I am dealing with a database of 5,000,000 rows and 3 fields and i am trying to index it with.

Here's what i do.:
After opening an index with Zend_Search_Lucene::open(); I query the database[correctly],
then put the results into $result1, fetch the query results and handle them with the following loop:

```
    while( ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_NUM)) ) {
                $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();           
                $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('catid',$row1[0]));
                $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('topic',$row1[1]));
                $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title',$row1[2]));

                $index->addDocument($doc);

    }
$index->optimize();
$index->commit();
```

The Problem is that i never get more than 3,000 addDocuments to work and every time the programm 'stalls' at `$index->addDocument($doc);` Never reaches more than 5,000 documents ,let alone commiting the index. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there any errors logged? Maybe you need to increase the memory limit in php.ini...

Comment: Are you running from command line ? If so the max_execution_time by default will be 0 . Else you may want to set http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time . I guess the script is getting stopped after certain time.

Comment: And also your can query from table with 5,000,000 rows like this `select * from tbl limit %u, 10000` instead of `select * from tbl`

Comment: @Hari K T .Man you are epic gold (: . That was it! I am running the index at the moment!Thx @azat and sorry @starsinmypockets for no additional information on errors.I'll have a better problem report next time! Be well!

Answer (score 1):

Moving comments to answers

@Faidon Passias Are you running from command line ?

If so the max_execution_time by default will be 0 .

Else you may want to set

[php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or

[php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) .

I guess the script is getting stopped after certain time.